# RMI - Does client side have to have definitions of used classes on server side?

Tags: java, rmi

I have simple client-server application using RMI. Server side is supposed to generate some sort of PDF (itext) file, and client should display it.

While trying to generate my pdf on server side by invoking proper method of my own common remote interface, `ClassNotFoundException` is thrown on **client side**.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.itextpdf.text.ExceptionConverter (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
```

I thought, that using RMI would be like using black box - client invokes method, and receives response, without knowlage of how it is done, to the only common class for both sides would be remote interface. More over i thought that this will allow me to shrink required dependencies on client side to minimum.

**Is it really mandatory for client to have all server's libraries in its classpath to work?**

EDIT:
Another strange fact is that there are no exceptions cought and logged on server side.
If I add server side project as dependency to client, that everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, it's probably not catching and handling `ExceptionConverter` on the server side properly and it's propagating to the client which has no definition for it.

Comment: Yes, this was my first shot, thats why I wrapped all methods into try-catch and throw only `RemoteException` with message. If I add my server side project as depenedcy to client application, that everything works fine. Any other ideas? need some code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable RMI-classloader AND set the appropriate system properties (google for: "java.rmi.server.codebase") then RMI will dynamically load the missing class from server to client - and your problem will go away. No need to store and statically link server libraries on client side.

As far as I know the [RMI-classloader tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/codebase.html) describes this all in detail.

EDIT:

I have given the hint to the great RMI-feature of dynamic classloading. But I would say in your special case it is probably not a good idea to try to propagate server classes to clients. Imagine there is another client like a JMX-browser in parallel which might get problems with unknown classes. Better: Catch the itext-Exception on server side just before sending the result of RMI-invocation and wrap it in another well-known exception like for example `IllegalStateException` **by only using the error message but not the stack trace** (you should log it anyway on the server-side).

My idea for exception handling on server-side is (pseudo-code):

```
try {
  // your server code
} catch (Throwable ex) {
  // a) log error completely including cause (stacktrace) with tools like Log4J etc.
  // b) throw new RemoteException(error.getMessage()); // without cause!
}
```

Comment: Yes I know of that, however I don't know why it is not cought on server side - all implemented remote methods are wrapped inside `try{}catch(Exception e)` blocks

Comment: As far as I understand dynamic loading, JVM cloud load needed classes (eg. for deserializing exceptions from server) from external resource. In my case however, no "unknown" objects are to be returned by server side. I think I may have something wrong with server side implementation.

Comment: @Antoniossss Maybe the iText-exception class is still in any stack trace and you just wrap this exception as `RemoteException` preserving the stack trace and therefore also the iText-Exception. My guess, please check how you handle it in your catch-clause.

Comment: I have some progress - `ClassDefNotFound` is not an exception but an error. That is why server did not cought anything. I have changed to throwable and I am investigation stacktrace.

Comment: Regarding your edit - this is how I am handling errors now - I was catching only `Excetpion` insteed of `Throwable` before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution.
It appears that I thought right - client does not have to know anything about what is under the hood of server implementation.
The key to everything, was static initialization block in one of our classes - resource used there could not beed resolved. As it was in static block, `IOException` was not cought and `Error` was generated insteed of exception. After changing all `catch`es from `Excetpion` to `Throwable` server did log proper stacktrace with the root cause (this was not included in stacktrace logged by client). Fixing it was just a matter of secodns.
Thank you for your time!